# Is it possible, and what is the syntax for a nested hash in Postgresql's HStore type?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, hstore

I'm not even sure that Postgres' HStore data type can contain nested hashes, and if they can, how to insert them?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
-- Database: test1

-- DROP DATABASE test1;
/*
CREATE DATABASE test1
  WITH OWNER = iainuser
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       TABLESPACE = pg_default
       LC_COLLATE = 'en_GB.UTF-8'
       LC_CTYPE = 'en_GB.UTF-8'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
*/
/* create extension hstore; */
/*drop table my_store;*/
/*
create table my_store (
  id serial primary key not null,
  doc hstore
);

CREATE INDEX my_store_doc_idx_gist
  ON my_store
  USING gist
  (doc);
*/
/* select doc from my_store; */
/*
insert into my_store (doc) values ( '"a" => "1"' );
select doc -> 'a' as first_key from my_store; -- returns "1"
*/

/* insert into my_store (doc) values ( '"b" => "c" => "3"' ); -- doesn't work */
/* insert into my_store (doc) values ( '"b" => ("c" => "3")' ); -- doesn't work */
/* insert into my_store (doc) values ( '"b" => hstore("c" => "3")' ); -- doesn't work */
/* insert into my_store (doc) values ( '"b"' => hstore("c" => "3")' ); -- doesn't work */
/* insert into my_store (doc) values ( "b"=>'"c"=>"3"'::hstore ); -- doesn't work */
```

If it's not possible, is there a current accepted standard/idiom for working with nested hashes - perhaps pull them apart and refer to them using id's?

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html):

> Keys and values are simply text strings.

So, no, you can't use an hstore as a value in an hstore. If you look at the [hstore operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html#HSTORE-OP-TABLE) and [functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html#HSTORE-FUNC-TABLE) you'll see that they all work with `text` values.

I don't know of any standard approach to faking nested hashes. I suspect you'd have to structure the keys (`a.b => c` for `a => b => c`), then you could so things like this:

```
select slice(doc, array['a.b', 'a.c'])
from my_store
where doc ?& array['a.b', 'a.c']
```

to grab the "a" slice of each `doc` that has the `{b => ..., c => ...}` "sub-hash".

There's also a [JSON type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-json.html) coming up that might be better suited to your needs. But, you'll have to wait for it and I'm not sure [what the final implementation will look like](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/JSON_API_Brainstorm).

Comment: If this doesn't give you want, you might be able to cast an hstore into text and then escape the quotes to get a string which could be saved as the value in an hstore, but it probably wouldn't be that convenient to use. You might want to consider normalizing the data a bit more.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, I appreciate it. I did read that page in the manual (and it is a fine manual) but it didn't even have an example of an insert, so wondered perhaps if there were more complex examples that had been left out too. @kgrittn I think the casting will be the route I end up taking, I don't need normalised data in this instance, (just a document as a blob really), unless that's the only way to get the document into the database!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone who sees this happens to be using ActiveRecord, [Nested Hstore](https://github.com/tombenner/nested-hstore) lets you store nested hashes in an hstore. It serializes the hstore values using JSON and supports a number of other data structures as well.